# LinkedIn framework for ios cannot log in

Tags: objective-c, ios, linkedin-api

I have to integrate linkedIn sharing in my app, I will be using [this framework](https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client).
It has a sample project. I open it, set up my apikey and secret key but the authorisation doesn't happen. Login window is opened and immediately closed,when I click get linkedIn profile. Also when I set up my linkedIn app, what should I put into JavaScript API domain? Now I put:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: myapikey
  authorize: true
</script>

- (void)initLinkedInApi
{
    apikey = @"myapikeys";
    secretkey = @"mysecretkey";   

    self.consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:apikey
                                        secret:secretkey
                                         realm:@"http://api.linkedin.com/"];

    requestTokenURLString = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken";
    accessTokenURLString = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken";
    userLoginURLString = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize";    
    linkedInCallbackURL = @"hdlinked://linkedin/oauth";

    requestTokenURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:requestTokenURLString] retain];
    accessTokenURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenURLString] retain];
    userLoginURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:userLoginURLString] retain];
}
```

And also I get this error:
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

Comment: Social sites change their interface frequently but that app hasn't been updated in 10 months.  You sure it still works?

Comment: Yet anyone who has implemented linked in sharing recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to put any javascript in the file at all.  The sample client (I just checked to make sure it works in the latest XCode and with IOS5.  All you need to do is put in your key and secret and it should just run in the simulator and on a dev device.

Why are you adding javascript into the code?

Comment: It asks to put JS API domain when you register you app(((

Comment: Yes, you need the JS API Domain if you are using Javascript.  For the iPhone sample client you are using the REST API, not Javascript.  So all you need to do is put in your API key and secret and the iPhone sample will run.

Comment: I mean, when I try to login it doesn't even offer to enter password  and login and returns null null((